# Can the Bluemix SSO service support multiple routes?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

we have an app running in bluemix under two different routes:
myapp.shortname.com
myapp.reallyreallyreallyreallylongname.com

but the SSO service does not work with myapp.shortname.com giving an error:

> CWOAU0062E: The OAuth service provider could not redirect the request
>   because the redirect URI was not valid. Contact your system
>   administrator to resolve the problem.

is it possible to support two routes or do we now have to run two NodeJS apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can register multiple redirect_uri for your client applications. For example:
"redirect_uris":[
"https://longNameHost:8999/resource/redirect1",
"https://shortnamehost:9000/resource/redirect2"
]

Comment: When I go into the config page in Bluemix and put in an array for the callback value I get the following error: `Error executing REST service FBTRBA183E The value [[aware.longname.com/auth/v1.0/sso_callback,https://… for [redirectURI] is not valid. –`

Comment: If I remove the [] and just but both URIs with a comma, I get the SSO login screen but then the same error: `CWOAU0062E: The OAuth service provider could not redirect the request because the redirect URI was not valid. Contact your system administrator to resolve the problem.`

Answer (score 0):

According to Bluemix SSO developer, the multiple redirect_uri capability is not exposed at this moment.